# How to define an object whose items can be accessed through a variable content in Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx

I'm new to typescript, trying to implement a content based on users browser language. Many different countries use the same language (with different locale keys) so i'm trying to filter them to avoid importing all locales from `date-fns` (which will be later on used).

```js
const availableLanguages = {
    es: 'es',
    pt: 'pt-BR',
    en: 'en-US'
}

const {i18n} = useTranslation(); // library for getting user locale

const browserLanguage = i18n.language.slice(0,2); // Handles pt-BR x pt-PT
const locale = availableLanguages[browserLanguage] // throws error
```

Last line throws

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ es: string; pt: string; en: string; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ es: string; pt: string; en: string; }'
```

error. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the `browserLanguage` is one of the keys of the object first:

```
if (browserLanguage !== 'es' && browserLanguage !== 'pt' && browserLanguage !== 'en') {
    // hopefully your app is designed so that this never occurs
    // but having this branch will make TS happy
    throw new Error('Language is not in availableLanguages');
}
const locale = availableLanguages[browserLanguage]
```

Other methods will require type assertions, eg:

```
if (!Object.keys(availableLanguages).includes(browserLanguage)) {
    throw new Error('Language is not in availableLanguages');
}
const locale = availableLanguages[browserLanguage as keyof typeof availableLanguages];
```

Comment: Is that the only way to do that? I implemented an object to avoid those inline comparations

Comment: something like
`if (browserLanguage in availableLangues)` as in python

Comment: It's possible, but it requires type assertion, which some prefer to avoid when possible - see edit

Comment: Thank you! I'll go for the first one ahah

Comment: why

```
if (browserLanguage in availableLanguages){
        const locale = availableLanguages[browserLanguage]
    }
``` does not work?

Comment: Because the `in` check still doesn't narrow the type of the `browserLanguage` - it's still a `string` inside the branch, instead of `'es' | 'pt' | 'en'`